# DQL symfony/ how to return the last id

Tags: sql, symfony, dql

Here's my code :

```
return $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('b')
    ->innerJoin('b.visiteurs', 'v')
    ->select("count(v.id)")
    ->where('b.visiteDate IS NOT NULL')
    ->groupBy('b.visiteDate')
    ->orderBy('b.id', 'DESC')
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

I'm trying to count the visitors I group by `visiteDate` and return only the count of the last `visiteDate` I flush. I have tried using `orderBY('b.id', 'DESC')` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the data type for 'visitDate' ?

Comment: the data type is datetime

Comment: I suggest you breakpoint screening, I estimate that there are two possibilities. A is your field type has a problem, one possibility is that the mapping relationship

Comment: Are you getting some errors? Paste here if any.